# 714Gig HD partition shows 652Gig full - only 285Gigs used - NOT DUPLICATE

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, disk-space

PLEASE HELP - but this is NOT A DUPLICATE question - please don't mark it as such before reading it. Several people marked last posting that way - clearly didn't read it. Yes, I have read through these forums for a few hours to no avail.

I have a Win7 laptop with a 750Gig C: drive.  It came partitioned with 714Gig usable from manufacturer.  I installed programs, music files, etc up to 285 gigs.  As of a few weeks ago it showed 285 Gigs.  Two weeks of house guests later and it shows HD is full.  I deleted some files but it still shows 652 Gigs on this drive while there are only 285 Gigs on drive.  Relevant details:

1. I am Administrator on laptop and have fair knowledge of what I am doing.
2. I did not restore from backup, restore from mirror, upgrade HD's or anything else that would have touched the partition structure.  Just daily use as imaging machine and web.
3. I have checked partitions under disk administrator - no change, still partitioned with 714Gigs usable.
4. Have looked through computer C drive by hand showing Hidden files and folders - no change.
5. I have used JDisk Report to double check - it shows I have only 285 Gigs on C drive.
6. I triple checked with TreeSize run as Administrator and it also shows 285 Gigs on C drive - yet Windows 7 still shows almost full.
7. I used Windows 7 Utilities to Check for Disk Errors, and Defragged the drive.  No errors shown and no change after Defrag.

I am stumped, and since this is a laptop from the factory, I really don't want to have to Format my HD.

PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: Hi Chris! Please edit your original question rather than reposting it. Just explain why the duplicates do not answer your question, but try and keep the meta to a minimum (e.g. not using "NOT A DUPLICATE" in the title). Thanks

Comment: Thanks for making sure I AGAIN have to post this.  I don't know how to remove the 'duplicate' tag that you put on my posts - and now I won't get a decent post.  Clearly if you wanted to be helpful you could have told me how to do that.  Thanks for screwing me.

Comment: Again: You would have just needed to [edit your original question](http://superuser.com/posts/576019/edit) rather than reposting your question, and explain why it's not a duplicate. Your question could have then be reopened. I edited your previous post and reopened it in the meantime.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what a Linux live CD shows on the drive to make sure that the OS or some virus is not hiding something from you.

Answer (score 0):

There are few common culprits which you should check:

- **Recycle Bin**: check it if is too big, and clean it up first: `Right Click` - > `Empty Recycle Bin`.
- **System restore points**. Often, you can reclaim significant space by removing restore points:
  `Start` -> `Control Panel` -> `System` -> `System Protection` -> `Configure` -> `Delete`.

You can also delete all restore points from command line:

```
vssadmin delete shadows /for=c: /all
```

Note that unlike any other files, space taken by restore points cannot be counted or revealed by normal tools, because it is hidden in `C:\System Volume Information` directory, which you do not have permission to look inside, even if you have full administrator rights.

- **Page file** at `C:\pagefile.sys`. Page file can grow to be rather large if you run something that needs a lot of memory. Check if this hidden file is bigger than few gigabytes.
- **Temporary files**. You can amass quite significant space of temporary files in `C:\Windows\TEMP` and/or `C:\Users\user\local settings\temp`. Make sure that these directories do not have large amount of files.
- **Software updates** downloaded at `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download`. As you run Windows updates, you can accumulate a lot of junk in this directory - you can safely remove its contents (but not directory itself).

I have surely forgotten about few other things, but these I would look up first.

Comment: Thank you for the the thoughts.  These have all been looked at already.  I also killed all the system restore points.  Anyone have any other ideas?  Hidden Backups besides the restore points?